# Django floatformat with forms.FloatField objects

Tags: django, format

`{{ value }}` works in my template.
`{{ myForm.myFloatField }}` works. `myForm` inherits from `forms.Form` and `myFloatField` is a `forms.FloatField` object.

`{{ value|floatformat:3 }}` presents the value with three numbers after the decimal, as expected.

`{{ myForm.myFloatField|floatformat:3 }}` does not work, not even rendering the field.

How do I get `myForm.myFloatField` to present with three numbers after the decimal?

Comment: `myForm.myFloatField` is a `Field` instance, it's not a number. You should render the `<input>` tag manually and use something like `<input ... value="{{ myForm.myFloatField.value|floatformat:3 }}>` to be able to do that.

Comment: @Selcuk, your solution would seem to discard all field properties except value. I'd like to keep those properties.

Comment: You should render them manually as well (hence the `...` part in my comment). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31373702/2011147) for starters.